# PHP 5.3 not recognizing short object syntax

Tags: php, syntax

I built a site in PHP 5.4 and when I just rolled it up on Windows I noticed that PHP 5.3.15 breaks when it runs into short object syntax such as `$dateGenerated = (new \DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Yes I can set this to a variable to resolve the issue.  I've done this kind of syntax all throughout my application and would like to know if there's still a clean way to handle it other than assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I believe your only option is to upgrade to PHP 5.4

Comment: @YogeshSuthar It doesn't really matter.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar What's your point?

Comment: So I think it cant be done. Maybe you can perform a regex search on `\(new (.*?\(.*?\))\)` and replace it by `\$var = $1; \$var`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar That is called namespacing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [new syntax feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) in PHP 5.4:

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().

So there's nothing to be done for it.

Comment: +1. nothing to be done... apart from upgrading to 5.4, of course.

Comment: Yep, it's not a problem; it's simply not available in the version of PHP that's being used.